# Multiple AND OR operator Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am wondering if it is correct to write in this way and am I using the brackets correctly?

*This is a code for a country redirects pop-up. The countryCode var is the country of the user (detected by API) while the localStorage.country is which country the user is in on the website.

Feel free to ignore the logic, I just need to know if IF Statement can be written in this way.

```
if((countryCode == 'sg/' && localStorage.country != "sg/") ||
(countryCode == 'ie/' && localStorage.country != "ie/") ||
(countryCode == 'my/' && localStorage.country != "my/")){
    /**  Country Redirect Pop Up **/
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `if (countryCode !== localStorage.country) {`?

Comment: I guess this can't work because what if I visit the site from Japan and the website doesn't have a Japan version. Meaning countryCode would equals to jp/ and localStorage.country will only be either sg/, ie/ or my/. In this case, the popup would have jumped up and ask to redirect the user to the Japan site (which is not available)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is valid and could also be written this way:

```
let acceptedCountryCodes = ['sg/', 'ie/', 'my/'];
if(countryCode !== localStorage.country && acceptedCountryCodes.includes(countryCode)){
    /**  Country Redirect Pop Up **/
}
```

Comment: May I know how would you write if the statement is acceptedCountryCode does not include(countryCode)?

Comment: ```!acceptedCountryCodes.includes(countryCode)```

Answer (score 3):

Sure, the code has no problem... It will check if 1st option OR 2nd option OR 3rd option is true

Comment: Thanks. But what if i take all the brackets out like this: 
`if(countryCode == 'sg/' && localStorage.country != "sg/" ||
countryCode == 'ie/' && localStorage.country != "ie/" ||
countryCode == 'my/' && localStorage.country != "my/"){
    /**  Country Redirect Pop Up **/
} `

WIll it still works?

Comment: no, because the OR and AND operators mess all of it up. I.E: paste this code in your console and you'll see what I mean: if (9 < 10 && 3 > 5 || 4 < 5) {
    console.log("YES")
} The working of the code is basically : if 9 is less than 10, and ( 3 is greater than 5 OR 4 < 5) not what you want

Comment: @codeRdevelopR `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so the code would work the same with or without the extra parentheses. Your console.log example will print "YES", but not because of the reason stated. See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) for a discussion of the operator precedence rules. In any case, the code can be written more simply as shown in Richard Lovell's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The code currently has no problem!

The wrapping brackets are **NOT** required in this case because **AND`(&&)`** operator has higher precedence than **OR`(||)`** operator.

Take a look at the following example:
`false && true || false && true` = `false`

The above example is similar to `(false && true) || (false && true)` which simplies to `false || false` therefore the final result is `false`.

Comment: I guess this can't work because what if I visit the site from Japan and the website doesn't have a Japan version. Meaning countryCode would equals to jp/ and localStorage.country will only be either sg/, ie/ or my/. In this case, the popup would have jumped up and ask to redirect the user to the Japan site (which is not available)

Comment: `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so the code would work the same with or without the extra parentheses. But you are right that it can be simplified. See Richard Lovell's answer for an example that takes into account the list of valid countries, and [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) for a discussion of the operator precedence rules.